# on flutter Widget without context cant use Navigator.push function on onPressed

Tags: flutter

If into a widget I try to use onPressed function Navigator.push it return error
this is the code

```
  Widget get _navigationDrawer {
    return Container(
      height: 60.0,
      child: BottomAppBar(
        color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
        elevation: 35,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.white,),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```

as you can see IconButton has onPressed function but if I add:

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
```

I got this error:
Compiler message:
lib/pages/profilepage.dart:62:36: Error: The getter 'context' isn't defined for the class 'UserProfile'.

- 'UserProfile' is from 'package:speedoo/pages/profilepage.dart' ('lib/pages/profilepage.dart').
  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'context'.
  Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));

Comment: Share the error along with more code to give us context in where this getter is. Additionally, provide code that includes `Navigator.push` somewhere. The code you posted doesn't have `Navigator.push` anywhere.

Comment: edited with error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BuildContext` isn't something that is globally available in a flutter app. `UserProfile` class is likely not a `Widget`(though I cannot tell as you haven't provided where this getter exists), and therefore doesn't automatically have access to `context`.

This can be easily solved by making this function **not** a getter, and making a `BuildContext` parameter. When you call this function, pass whatever context is available at that moment.

```dart
Widget _navigationDrawer(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 60.0,
      child: BottomAppBar(
        color: Color(0xFF1f2032),
        elevation: 35,
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35),
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.settings,color: Colors.white,),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));

                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }
```